# Can not retrieve Principal from Spring Okta (CRA SPA)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, okta

I am currently trying to test out Okta with SPA front end (Create-React-App) and a Spring Boot application.

Currently I have the apps working, in that a user logins on the front end (via okta). The user can then access protected resources from server (spring boot). Hence the integration works well and nice.

My issue is I can't access the Principal on my Rest Controller.

**ENV**

Note: Spring-Security-Starter is NOT on the classpath just the OAuth2 autoconf

- Spring Boot 2.0.6.RELEASE
- okta-spring-boot-starter:0.6.1
- spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.0.6.RELEASE'

**Spring Configuration**

```
okta.oauth2.issuer=https://dev-886281.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default
okta.oauth2.clientId={ clientId }
okta.oauth2.audience=api://default
okta.oauth2.scopeClaim=scp
okta.oauth2.rolesClaim=groups

security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=https://dev-886281.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo
```

**Okta Service Configuration**

```
   Application type: Single Page App (SPA)
   Allowed grant types: Implicit
   Allow Access Token with implicit grant type: true
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {
...
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<ProductEntity>> getAllProducts(Principal principal) {
```

**SpringBoot**

```
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class CartyApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CartyApplication.class, args);
}

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
protected static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }
}

@Bean
protected ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter resourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
        }
    };
}
```

Once again the overall integration is working fine, users can only access protected resources once they've signed in via okta, I'm just wondering how to get the users details from okta on the controller.

Thanks in advance.

P.S soz for the code dump

EDIT: Removed snippets and added full CartyApplication class

EDIT2: Added repo - https://github.com/Verric/carty-temp

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you might be missing this:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    protected static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I do have the exact same expression handler setup, in the code snippet above. I omitted the class definition for brevity, but I do have the exact (word for :p) in my spring boot class :(

Comment: Please check SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication, its coming as null?

Comment: No, it is not coming in as null, it contains bearer token but no user details or principal 
Add image link if it help
https://i.imgur.com/VbO0Cdq.png

Comment: Cool, try this: public ResponseEntity<List<ProductEntity>> getAllProducts(JwtAuthenticationToken token) {    Principal p = (Principal)        oauth2.getPrincipal();
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing should remove the `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` line.
See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#CO3-2

I'm guessing you want to protect all/most of your endpoints?  I'd recommend only allowing specific routes, and protecting everything else.

Comment: Correct in the future this will be restricted, for the time being my primary focus is trying to figure out how to extract the users details from the spring-okta integration. Allow all just makes things easy to start with.... hopefully :p

Comment: it also means you are not requiring authentication, which may explain why you have an empty SecurityContext. I think this will need to change before you can continue.

Comment: Apologies Brian, I've updated the code so only Option requests get through, however still no luck, apologies for my misunderstanding